# How to use generic type in function with constraint (C++)

Tags: c++

I have an algorithm that needs to be executed with many implementations of a parent class named "Stack" (i.e. "LinkedStack", "ArrayStack", etc).
I figured out that if I write this algorithm into a function and provide some sort of generic typing/template function magic, the problem would be solved.

But I didn't find any means to do so.

I've searched and tried many syntaxes but maybe it's just not possible?

```cpp
template<class T: Stack> // Imaginary synthax to tell "T is a Stack"
void doTaskWithSpecificImplementation() 
{
    // Eventually somewhere in the function:
    T stack = new T();
}

void main() {
    doTaskWithSpecificImplementation<LinkedStack>();
}
```

I expect this code to provide a short and easy way to call a function while prescribing the use of specific virtual class implementation.

Comment: I'm gonna infer that you're coming from java or similar where you can have `extends` on a generic type. Typically C++ uses more of a compile-time duck-typing approach (though this will shift with Concepts).

Comment: @MaxVollmer Indeed, it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't mention overloading, but simply giving a comprehensible error when you get the wrong type. In this case, `static_assert` with `std::is_base_of`

```
template<typename T>
void doTaskWithSpecificImplementation() {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Stack, T>{}, "T must be a Stack or a Stack subclass");
}
```

Comment: sfinae would be a better solution: what if down the road we want a different impl if it's not a stack?

Comment: The static_assert is expedient, SFINAE makes for verbose and somewhat opaque compile time error messages.  If it is a shared code base, SFINAE is probably the better choice.  If it is entirely internal to a specific project, it's a judgement call.